# Searching for datasets of face mask images

Tags: data-request, images, faces

I am searching for open datasets containing images of humans (or human heads, with or without background) wearing face masks, preferably medical FFP masks.

Context/scenery is not important. Annotated datasets would be beneficial, but images only would also be highly appreciated.

Images should cover at least the complete head of a human wearing a face mask like this: [image: example of human wearing face mask]

Answer (score 1):

You can use Real World Masked Face Dataset -

https://github.com/X-zhangyang/Real-World-Masked-Face-Dataset